# How can I create a table to generate columns from query row results?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, datatable

I'm trying to generate a new table from an existing table like so.
I want the column "ProjectName" from the Current Table to return distinct values as new columns in the Result Table.
I then want the rows to return column distinct UserID, calculate the total TimeIn and TimeOut for each project for each individual user.

I would then like to put the results in an aspx gridview or just a html table.

See image below:

[image]

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you have any code / attempts to show us?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL Server

Comment: you should use pivote concept

Comment: please provide your data in format  text its easy for others to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As you din't mention any thing what you tried so far
Try this Query may be it helps you**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (
        Select ID  
              ,UserID
              ,Manager

          From Your_Table
       ) A
 Pivot (max([ProjectName]) For [TimeIn] in (' + Stuff((Select Distinct ','+QuoteName (TimeIn) 
                    From Your_Table A  
                    Order By 1 
                    For XML Path('')),1,1,'')  + ') ) p'
--Print @SQL
Exec(@SQL)
```